# How to move ElementHandle to another Page

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

I am attempting to iterate an array of ElementHandles and append these into a second Page like so:

```
const htmlContent: string = `
    <html><head></head><body>
        <div class="section">Section 1</div>
        <div class="section">Section 2</div>
        <div class="main-container"></div>
    </body></html>`

let browser: Browser = await Puppeteer.launch();
const firstPage: Page = await browser.newPage();
const secondPage: Page = await browser.newPage();
await firstPage.goto('data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,' + htmlContent);
await secondPage.goto('data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,' + htmlContent);
let sections: ElementHandle[] = await firstPage.$$('.section');

for (const section of sections) {
    secondPage.$eval('.main-container', (el: any, section: ElementHandle) => {
        el.append(section);
    }, section);
}

browser.close()
```

I base this code on the Puppeteer documentation for class ElementHandle:

> ElementHandle instances can be used as arguments in page.$eval() and page.evaluate() methods.

However, this does not work. It generates a stacktrace with the following message:

> Error: JSHandles can be evaluated only in the context they were created!

I tried to define the section as `any` and also `JSHandle` with the same result.
I've been searching through the api documentation for any hints as to what I'm doing wrong without result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ‘context’ the error message refers to is the page—you’re trying to copy elements from one page to another, which it simply won’t let you do, and unfortunately there’s no way to serialize them so you can pass them. That said, as long as losing any out-of-band data (such as event listeners or other properties set in JavaScript) is acceptable, you can copy the `outerHTML` instead:

```
const htmlContent: string = `
<html><head></head><body>
<div class="section">Section 1</div>
<div class="section">Section 2</div>
<div class="main-container"></div>
</body></html>`;

let browser: Browser = await Puppeteer.launch();
const firstPage: Page = await browser.newPage();
const secondPage: Page = await browser.newPage();
await firstPage.goto("data:text/html;charset=UTF-8," + htmlContent);
await secondPage.goto("data:text/html;charset=UTF-8," + htmlContent);
let sectionsAsHtml: string[] = await firstPage.$$eval(
  ".section",
  (elements: Element[]) => Array.from(elements).map(e => e.outerHTML)
);

for (const section of sectionsAsHtml) {
  await secondPage.$eval(".main-container", e => (e.innerHTML += section));
}

browser.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that the ElementHandle was bound to `firstPage`. Your solution worked perfectly.
I do hope the Puppeteer team adds support for moving ElementHandles between contexts in the future though.

Comment: Glad it helped. I think support for this is unlikely because of the out-of-band data—it may not matter to your case, but I would guess that if it were possible to copy `ElementHandle`s the user would expect them to be copied wholesale, which doesn’t make sense when you have, for example, arbitrary event handlers whose context is also that parent document.

Comment: True. Maybe a middleground would be a function that serializes the `ElementHandle`. Either way, thanks again for the help!